# Bluetooth dual pairing. Mic and speakers. App?

Tags: bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

I would like to run a https://www.headwave.de/ 
speaker on my motorbike helmet and a separate Bluetooth mic.
The speaker is only for music but will play phone call audio.

The question is: Is there an app that will let me separate the in and out channels within Bluetooth so I can connect two individual Bluetooth devices at the same time?

I am using an HTC1 android.
They have it on the turtle beach headsets for PlayStation and Xbox.